# Qual è il significato di "fardella"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> Il Bajona, forse perché scapolo e in più napolitano, teneva passione solo per le **fardelle**. Crucilla Francavilla Marchiafava Giudecca e tutto il Vascio erano i suoi quartieri. Andava a 'na cert'ora, pancia in avanti e baffi impomatati, la busta bianca in una mano, bussava alla porta col marito a riposo dentro la Vicarìa o pure a Favignana. «Chi è?», «Songo Bajona, 'a ligge, aprite! Tengo notizie do marito vosto». Tric e trac ed era dentro.

Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa "fardella"? Non ho trovato questo vocabolo in nessun dizionario. Si tratta di un termine di origine siciliana?

Comment: Dal contesto, sembra che si intenda con questa parola (che non conosco) le donne i cui mariti sono in prigione.

Comment: Penso si tratti dell'italianizzazione del vocabolo siciliano "fadedda" che, secondo questo [*Supplemento ai vocabolari
siciliani* di Gerhard Rohlfs](https://publikationen.badw.de/de/003584244.pdf)
ha il significato di "gonnella" o "sottana" (l'equivalente catalano sarebbe "faldilla", che significa "gonna"). In questo brano, la passione del Bajona per le "fardelle" avrebbe il senso figurato di un interesse sessuale per le donne.

Answer (score 1):

Secondo l'articolo [*Plurilinguismo in Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio 
di Vincenzo Consolo*, di Nicolò Messina](https://www.academia.edu/11715857/Plurilinguismo_in_Il_sorriso_dellignoto_marinaio_di_Vincenzo_Consolo), si tratta di un napoletanismo con il significato di "gonnella":

> Nel cap. II (29-31) si fa avanti lo sbirro Bajona, che intride già di napoletanismi la stessa digressione che gli fa da piedistallo, nella forma sia dell'indiretto libero: (29) *teneva passione per le fardelle* (con lo scambio *tenere/avere* e *fardelle* <gonnelle> < *farda* 
>   <gonna>, cfr. sp. *falda*) [...]

In questo brano, la passione del Bajona per le "fardelle" avrebbe il senso figurato di un interesse sessuale per le donne.

Comment: Veramente, cambiando la "r" con la "l" (fenomeno frequente), trovo che "fardella" assomiglia molto al catalano "faldilla", che significa "gonna". E, se il significato del vocabolo è simile a quello di "faldilla", il senso della frase diventa chiarissimo perché in catalano abbiamo espressioni analoghe con "faldilles".

Comment: È possibile che il siciliano abbia forti influenze dallo spagnolo, a causa della dominazione borbonica, non so se lo spagnolo abbia una parola simile a faldilla

Comment: @DenisNardin: Secondo l'autore dell'articolo che ho citato, si tratta di un napoletanismo e non di un sicilianismo. In spagnolo esiste il termine "falda", che significa "gonna".